# US Passport with e-visa going to Istanbul Turkey

Tags: visas, transit, us-citizens, cdg

Do I need another visa for my layover in Paris? with Delta airlines. My layover is 11 hours. Can I stay in the airport for that long? is CDG open 24 hours? My final stop is Istanbul, Turkey which I have an e-visa

Answer (score 2):

As a US citizen, you do not need a specific visa to visit France for a short time, including a flight layover. You might be able to stay at the airport for 11 hours, depending on when and where you arrive. From https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/services/claims-litigation/faq (June 2022):

> Closing times at Paris-Charles de Gaulle airport terminals:
>
> - Terminal 1: 12:00 am to 04:00 am
> - Terminal 2A: 12:30 am to 03:30 am
> - Terminal 2B: Closed for renovation.
> - Terminal 2C: 11:00 pm to 04:00 am
> - Terminal 2D: 11:30 pm to 04:30 am
> - Terminal 2E: 12:00 am to 04:00 am
> - Terminal 2F: 12:00 am to 04:00 am
> - Terminal 2G: 11:30 pm to 05:00 am
> - Terminal 3: 11:30 pm to 04:30 am